# Is this truth table correct?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

Is this truth table correct? Sorry for the formatting

Truth table for $p ∧ c$ and $p ∨ c$, with $c$ representing a contradiction:

$$\begin{array}{cc|cc}
p & c & p∧c&p∨c  \\ \hline
T & F & F & T \\
F & F & F & F
\end{array}
$$

Comment: Why do you have F in the upper right corner?

Comment: Is it correct now?

Comment: **"table is correct now"** $= T$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, assuming you are using $c$ to denote a contradiction, then your truth-table is just fine.

Another way you might want to signify a contradiction is by using $\bot$: `\bot`, and just as an FYI, you can denote a tautology $\top$: `\top`.  These are more universally recognized as contradiction, tautology, respectively. As you can see, some may mistaken $c$ as signifying a variable which can be assigned the truth-values "T" and "F".

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
&p &c &&p\land c &&p\lor c \\  
&T &T &&T        &&T \\
&T &F &&F        &&T\\
&F &T &&F &&T\\
&F &F &&F &&F
\end{align}

just according to the definitions of the truth functions 
$$\lor:\{T,F\}\rightarrow\{T,F\}$$
and
$$\land:\{T,F\}\rightarrow\{T,F\}$$

Comment: c is a contradiction in my problem.

Comment: so u take the 2nd and 4th rows of the above truth table and lookm up the outcome then only depending on the value of $p$?